# Генерация данных для отправки на почту

Tags: python, email, smtplib

Нужно отправить данные на электронную почту, делаю отправку в виде таблицы. За основу взял данный код: https://gist.github.com/ripiuk/2defb27fa633a6deb1bd328d20cc4479

Проблема в том, что содержание ячеек у меня меняются, так как данные добавляются. У меня получается отправить на почту данные, но отдельном письмом. А нужно в одном. Для этого нужен цикл, как я думаю. Но внутри реализовать не получается. Пробовал jinja2, но безуспешно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В примере письма использую HTML и f-строки, чтобы вставить переменные, которые я получил

Comment: Проблему решил с помощью jinja2. Все данные добавил в список, далее по циклу прошелся и нагенерировал HTML-код для письма. Получилась таблица с данными и всё в одном письме